# How to get an specific kind/type of query in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to collect all querys that I have been using from the query_history table, however, I only want to take the querys that have been used for DML purposes like:

UPDATE, INSERT, ALTER (ALTER_*), RENAME, MERGE, DELETE, TRUNCATE_*, DROP, COPY, SELECT, CREATE (CREATE_*)

Any advice please? I am a beginner

Answer (score 1):

Filtering based on the SQL texts may be misleading as the object names or comments can contain these keywords. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE_UPDATE_V1;

/* updated the filter */ SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE X  = 1;
```

Account_usage.query_history view has a column named QUERY_TYPE:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/query_history

If you want to list the DML queries, you can look for INSERT, DELETE, MERGE, TRUNCATE_TABLE, and COPY:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql-dml

```
select start_time, query_type, query_text from snowflake.account_usage.query_history 
where start_time > '2023-01-01'
and query_type in ('INSERT', 'DELETE', 'MERGE', 'TRUNCATE_TABLE', 'COPY');
```

Answer (score 0):

This query example should do it:

```
select *
from table(information_schema.query_history(dateadd('hours',-4,current_timestamp()),current_timestamp()))
where query_text ilike 'update%' or query_text ilike 'insert%' or query_text ilike 'drop%' or query_text ilike 'select%'
order by start_time;
```

I've only added a few type of statements but you can adjust to your need. Also you can adjust the period, as I've set it to 4 hours.